# How can I have an exception for a rule in my .htaccess file?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, trailing-slash

Probably very easy question but I can't get it to work.

**Case:**
The trailing slash will be removed from the URL by the following htaccess line:

```
RewriteCond %{request_method} ^GET$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)/$
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ %1 [L,R=301] # <- this line removes the trailing slash
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

How can I make an exception for this page:
`mydomain.com/paypal/ipn/`
so it won't do a 301 redirect to: `mydomain.com/paypal/ipn`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an exception using `RewriteCond`:

```
RewriteCond %{request_method} ^GET$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/paypal/ipn/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ %1 [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```